# How to change Text field to Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Can any body tell me the best practice or way to change Text field to the Button with value 0 or 1.

Let me clear what I want so i have here(see below) django form with the 2 field called Up_vote and Down_vote and when I submit it stores pretty nicely into the Votes table.

[image]

But what I what is to have two buttons like stacoverflow have for up_vote and down_vote and when someone press on the up_vote it should submit value 1 automatically to the database and when someone press the down_Vote it sould submit the value 0 to the database table.

see like this:
[image]

so basically how i can convert text fields to the two buttons, I dont now how i can do with the javascript or with other method.

Comment: Vote early, vote often? Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @nigel222  the first on the top is data retrived from the server

Comment: I've done things like this with a spot of JQuery. Make the Django fields hidden, or put them in a div that your Jquery hides at document ready time. Add a couple of buttons styled as up and down with onClick callbacks. The callback can stuff the value into the Django form field and submit  it. Alternatively, dispense with Django forms altogether and just pull the user choice of Up or Down out of request.POST in your view function when your JQuery POSTs.

Comment: @nigel222 thank you i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a CSS style I will assume that you will not use AJAX

1. Create 2 forms one for up and other for down vote
2. Put the `type` attribute on the input to hidden and the `value` is 1 for the up vote and 0 for down vote and use CSS to style the submit button to appear like what you want

this how it should be in html

```
<!-- Up vote form -->
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="vote" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="up-vote-btn"></button>
</form>
<!-- Down vote form -->
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="vote" value="0">
    <button type="submit" class="up-vote-btn"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: ok, then how i am going to submit this data to the django models form?

Comment: it will work as normal form you will change just the style.